# (Teaching) references for computational complexity

Tags: references, teaching, time-complexity

Background: I am going to teach computational complexity (time complexity) within an introductory course in machine learning. I would like to gently introduce the notion of computational complexity and then overview some machine learning algorithms from that perspective, showing what happens when either the sample size or the number of features grows. Therefore:

I am looking for a reference (a textbook, a book chapter, a paper, a blog post) on computational complexity that would be pedagogical and accessible for students with limited math skills.

Comment: The only thread tagged with both [tag:references] and [tag:time-complexity] so far is ["Reference summarizing various machine learning algorithms' computational complexity"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212899/) with a helpful link to a blog post ["Computational complexity of machine learning algorithms"](https://www.thekerneltrip.com/machine/learning/computational-complexity-learning-algorithms/).